# Google App Script Attaching an image from an OverGridImage to a MailApp email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, email-attachments

I'm trying to create a form using Google Sheets.  The user can input data into cells, some stuff is done, and an email is sent.  I want to include the ability to add image snips to that email by pasting them over cells in the sheet.  I can collect an OverGridImage array using

```
var images = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input').getImages();
```

and I have the email all sorted using

```
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    cc: cc,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments:attachments

  });
}
```

But I'm very stuck on changing the OverGridImage array into something that I can pass as an attachment to MailApp.

Comment: Can I ask you about `I'm very stuck on changing the OverGridImage array into something that I can pass as an attachment to MailApp.`? What mimeType do you want to convert the OverGridImage to? And when there are several images, how do you want the OverGridImages to convert to the attachment file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you want cannot be done. Google Sheets doesn't have the capacity to return the blob of an image, only a reference to the image which means that you cannot retrieve the images and attach them afterwards in an e-mail using Google Apps Script.

An alternative would be to use the `=IMAGE()` function to insert the **images in a cell** and afterwards you can retrieve them by using the [**Sheets API V4**](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest).